# Allow Chrome PHP

Tags: php, http

This is my first php coding and i would like to know how can i allow chrome browser to visit a certain page.

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'] || $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'] || $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] || $_SERVER['HTTP_VIA']) {
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=http://google.com\">";
}

if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) )
{
  $t_bIsChrome = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome');
  if ( $t_bIsChrome !== false)
  {
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=http://google.com\">";
    exit;
  }
}

echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=2.php\">";
?>
```

It does work with fireforx but when i try doing it on chrome it actually redirects it to the link which is after echo.

What i would like here is to allow chrome to visit the url as it does on firefox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What user agent string do you get while using Chrome?

Comment: If this is in any way intended for security, scrap it. You can't trust any of the pieces of information you are checking there, and all someone would need is to know the "real" URL and the whole thing would be pointless anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try a header redirect:

```
<?php
header('Location: google.com');
exit;
?>
```

using a meta refresh is not recommended in PHP

Comment: I have tried this by replacing with your code above but it does the same thing on chrome exactly what i posted above.

Comment: I do not understand, do you want to redirect to google.com? just replace `echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=http://google.com\">";` with `header('Location: google.com);`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you are willing to do with this code, but it actually restricts Chrome to visit 2.php, the reason Firefox is able to redirect is you don't test it for Firefox.

So if you want Chrome to visit, remove the user agent testing, and it'll be OK.

Anyway, as fixnode said, NEVER EVER redirect a browser like this, always use header('Location: ') for it!

Comment: Actually i want to scrap the whole code of chrome. Like i said it basically redirect the url on firefox but when i do the same on chrome it redirect it to the url posted in the code above. i.e. google.com. I have tried removing the the user agent testing and now it won't load.